# Use right Equals method when use generic type in C#

Tags: c#

I have classes:

```
public class A : IEquatable<A>
{
  ...
  public bool Equals(A data) { ... }
}

public class B
{
   ...
}
```

and a generic class for custom job

```
public class CommonFilter<T>
{
   public T GetBy(T data) {
      var item = list.FirstOrDefault(s=> s?.Equals(data) == true);
      ...
   }
}
```

`list` if `List<T>` type.

```
CommonFilter<A> cmA = GetFilter();
var result = cmA.GetBy(data);
```

In debug mode, if I have object like `CommonFilter<A>`, I expected that in LINQ to use `Equals` method from `A` class, but it doesn't.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: You also need to override `Equals(object)` in `A`.

Comment: I know because I put breakpoint in VS 2019, it is not reached

Comment: IIRC, `EqualityComparer<T>.Equals(s, data)` should select the right `Equals`.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to know for sure why your code doesn't work. However, most likely you haven't fully implemented equality in your type. See marked duplicate, as well as the hundreds of other equality-related questions on Stack Overflow, for details about how to do it correctly. If you still are having trouble after reviewing all of that material, post a new question but this time make sure you provide a proper [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem with an explanation of what _specifically_ you can't figure out.

Comment: Further, it is possible that your call site simply doesn't have access to the full type information and thus is calling the wrong `Equals()` method. This would not be an issue if you'd implemented equality correctly (since the `object.Equals()` method would work just as well as the interface method, albeit with boxing overhead), but you can get away with it if you declare your constraint correctly. See other marked duplicate for that particular issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, Gvien that two people have successfully answered the question, I think it's fair to say the question was clear enough.

Comment: @Jasper: a) people guessing the right answer doesn't make the question clear enough, b) no one should've been answering a question that's already been answered plenty of times before, and c) no one should tolerate a debugging question that doesn't include a [mcve].

Comment: a) I didn't guess; the answer was clear. b) True, but I never mentioned it c) I didn't need to debug, the answer was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jasper points out, you are missing a generic constraint:

```
public class CommonFilter<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
```

Whats not explained in the other answer is why its needed.

Bear in mind that the compiler needs to resolve the call `s?.Equals(data)` at compile time. In your code the compiler knows nothing about `T` and therefore resolves the call to the only possible candidate for any `T`: `object.Equals` which defaults to reference comparison.

If, on the other hand, you define the constraint then the compiler *knows* that any given `T` must implement the more specific `IEquatable<T>.Equals` and will resolve the call to that method.

If defining the constraint is a breaking change or you simply can't implement it because you also need to process data where reference equality is appropiate then you could branch inside `GetBy` on whether `T` implements `IEquatable<T>` or not, Type checking a generic type is normally a red flag but it could be justifiable in this particular scenario.

If possible, I prefer the first option because that way you specifically forbid using `GetBy` with types that do not implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: Always love answers like this. Explaining the *why* is just as important as the *what*, if not more important.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
public class CommonFilter<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
```